# Implementing a PIVOT query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

How can I pivot the following SELECT statement:

```
         SELECT sc.CID,
                sc.CodeName     as OverviewText,
                scRAG.CodeName  as RAGStatusText 
           FROM StatusCode      sc
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectOverview po 
             ON sc.CID          = po.ProjectOverviewCID 
            AND po.ProjectId    = 180
LEFT OUTER JOIN StatusCode      scRAG 
             ON po.RAGStatusCID = scRAG.CID
          WHERE sc.SCID         = 18
```

Such statement yields the result set that follows:

```
CID OverviewText    RAGStatusText
--- ------------    -------------
153 Cost            Green
154 Requirements    Yellow
155 Schedule        NULL
156 Technical       NULL
157 Testing         NULL
```

But, I want it to return one single row with 10 values, as shown bellow:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Cost | Green | Requirements | Yellow | Schedule | NULL | Technical | NULL | Testing | NULL |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can I pivot on `CID`?

Comment: You might want to look at the following answered question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/875/247

Comment: How are these related? You need a column that relates the information to each other.

Comment: @eric, can i pivot on CID? thats what i was trying to do with no luck

Comment: You need something common to every record. And you would get back 5 columns with 5 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want. But It gives your expected result. Note you can rename the columns as you please.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @t table(
    cid int,
    OverviewText varchar(15),
    RAGStatusText varchar(15)
 )

insert into @t values (153, 'Cost',           'Green');
insert into @t values (154, 'Requirements',   'Yellow');
insert into @t values (155, 'Schedule',       'NULL');
insert into @t values (156, 'Technical',      'NULL');
insert into @t values (157, 'Testing',        'NULL');


Select 
    [153|1] as [xyz],
    [153|2],
    [154|1],
    [154|2],
    [155|1],
    [155|2],
    [156|1],
    [156|2],
    [157|1],
    [157|2]

FROM (
select CAST(cid as varchar) + '|1' type, OverviewText  text from @t
Union
select CAST(cid as varchar) + '|2' type, RAGStatusText text from @t
) as SourceTable
Pivot(
    min(text)
    for type in ([153|1],[153|2], [154|1],[154|2], [155|1],[155|2], [156|1],[156|2], [157|1],[157|2])
) as PivotTable;
```